# Blank Page after executing insert query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

After executing the below query , codeigniter displays a blank page, i think there is a syntax error in the insert query and also not able to print the query. Please help

My Model code is as follows:

```
function add_new_user($email,$password,$username)
{

    $sqls="INSERT INTO pr_users (username,userpass,email,departmentid,userroleid,managerid,userlevel,branchid,is_global,registrationtime,timemodified,modifierid,status,deleted,temppass,temppassvalidtill,lastlogin,lastrefresh,lastloginip,if_online,pfield) values ('".$email."','".65e1b655a6d6f4cbed20554d3b52521a743afdc0."','".$email."','".1."','".4."','".10."','".4."','".2."','".0."','".0."','".1491557947."','".1."','".1."','".0."','".."','".0."','".1492084067."','".1492084083."','".::1."','".0."','".unfold983$."')";
    $query=$this->db->query($sqls);

    $result = $this->db->last_query();  
    return $result;

}
```

Comment: Are you serious? putting "die" will allow execution of page?

Comment: die; after nothing will be execute

Comment: removed die and still the same

Comment: need to echo like this  echo $this->db->last_query(); die;

Comment: you are using a framework here! And exposing yourself to SQL injection. this is beyond interesting

Comment: @Akin instead of deriding them, you could offer some helpful suggestions to improving the code.

Comment: I would recommend to use codeigniter's inbuilt query builder class's function. It will simplify your coding. For insertion you need to use insert method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
function add_new_user($email,$password,$username)
{
    $sqls="INSERT INTO pr_users (username,userpass,email,departmentid,userroleid,managerid,userlevel,branchid,is_global,registrationtime,timemodified,modifierid,status,deleted,temppass,temppassvalidtill,lastlogin,lastrefresh,lastloginip,if_online,pfield) values ('$email','65e1b655a6d6f4cbed20554d3b52521a743afdc0','$email','1','4','10','4','2','0','0','1491557947','1','1','0','','0','1492084067','1492084083','1','0','unfold983$')";
    $query=$this->db->query($sqls);

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        echo "Success";
        # return TRUE;
    } 
    else {
        echo "failed";
        # return FALSE;
    }

}
```

> **Note:** Make sure in `index.php`(in root) environment is `development`

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development'); # line 21
```

---

### As well *Highly Recommended* to use [Codeigniter Query Builder Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line:

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

With:

```
$result = $this->db->last_query();  
return $result;
```

Comment: try to echo the `$result` value

Comment: $this->db->last_query();  is give the last executed query

Comment: @JYoThI I think `sunshine` wants to return the query only.

Comment: remove all the **"** in `values()` and try the insert query.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your insert statement like this:
check your last parameter also.It seems to me, you need to escape the '$'

```
`$sqls="INSERT INTO pr_users  (username,userpass,email,departmentid,userroleid,managerid,userlevel,branchid,is_global,registrationtime,timemodified,modifierid,status,deleted,temppass,temppassvalidtill,lastlogin,lastrefresh,lastloginip,if_online,pfield) values ('".$email."','65e1b655a6d6f4cbed20554d3b52521a743afdc0','".$email."','1','4','10','4','2','0','0','1491557947','1','1','0','','0','1492084067','1492084083','::1','10','unfold983\$')";`
```

Comment: just echo yourb `$sqls` & paste it here

Comment: or check it from your log what is the error.set error_reporting 'ON' also